# How can I write the results of a SQL query to azure cloud storage?

Tags: sql, azure

Our current data set is not friendly in terms of looking at historic records. I can see what a value for an account is at the time of execution but if I want to look up last month's counts and values that's often lost. To fix this I want to take a "snapshot" of our data by running it at specific times and storing the results in the cloud. We're looking at just over 30,000 records and I'd only run it at the end of the month keeping 12 separate months at a time so the count doesn't get too high.

I can't seem to find anything about how I could do this so I'm hoping someone has experience or knowledge and would like to share.

FYI we're using an on premise oracle DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) (ADF) to schedule a monthly run for a pipe that execute a query/stored procedure against your Azure SQL and writes the data to Azure Storage.